# Is it possible to convert classical oracle to quantum ones?

Tags: cryptography, oracles

If an attacker possesses a classical oracle, so she could apply chosen plain text attacks. Is there an easy way to reduce this oracle to quantum ones allowing her to make quantum chosen plain text attacks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the general setting, no. [Simon's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simon%27s_problem) is a good example of it: having only a classical access to $f$, the best possible algorithms are exponential, even if the adversary has a quantum computer. If they have a quantum access to it however, then they can recover $s$ in polynomial time (Simon's algorithm has been designed to show that such cases exist in the first place).

All in all, this depends on what you mean by "easy way". Given a classical access to $f$, what you can do is querying $f$ for all possible inputs in order to know it completely. Once done, it is easy to build a quantum circuit implementing $f$, but this means you had to query $f$ on an exponential number of inputs, not to mention that once you entirely know $f$, it is likely that you don't have any remaining use of a quantum oracle implementing it.

That said, there is a particular case that comes to my mind in regards of the quantum advantage provided by a quantum oracle. It has been shown in [this article](https://eprint.iacr.org/2020/596.pdf) that if you choose a random function $f$, and if the adversary is not allowed to use its output register, that is, the adversary sends $\sum_x\alpha_x|x\rangle$ and the oracle sends back $\sum_x\alpha_x|x\rangle|f(x)\rangle$, then the adversary can't reliably know whether you measure its input. Putting things differently, no matter what the adversary does, it cannot gain any advantage using this oracle rather than a classical one. So, in that case, there is a reduction between the quantum oracle and the classical one.